# how call a function with parameters in eax and esi. gcc c++

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, usercall

I need to call a function pointer using gcc that i can´t typedef in c++. I´m not good at asm so i would appreciate your help.

The function passes arg1 in eax and arg2 in esi. args are pushed right to left and the caller cleans the stack

```
signed int __usercall o_Fkt<eax>(int a1<eax>, int a2<esi>, int a3, int a4, int a5)
```

edit:
Thanks Willem. I had success calling it this way:

```
    int callfn(void* a1, void* a2, int a3, int a4, void* a5 )
    {
        int result;
        unsigned long fktAddr = 0x0092FE40;
        __asm volatile(
                "push %[a5]\n\t"
                "push %[a4]\n\t"
                "push %[a3]\n\t"
                "call edx\n\t"
                "add esp, 12"
                : "=a" (result)
                :  "d" (fktAddr), "a" (a1), "S" (a2) , [a5] "r" (a5), [a4] "r" (a4), [a3] "r" (a3)
                : "memory"
        );
        return result;
    }
```

edit2: added "memory" to clobber list

Comment: Why do you need a typedef? Why not simply declare a function pointer as `int (*fun_ptr)(int,int,int,int)`=some_func; And call it as `fun_ptr(x,y,z,a);`?

Comment: i normally typedef the functions i´m calling like: typedef int(__thiscall* tFunc(void* pThis, ...); tFunc pFunc = addr; then i call it. but for setting eax and esi i have to use asm and just setting these two before the call was not successfull.

Answer (score 2):

something like this - i did not test it, but the compiler output looks ok i think.

```
int oFkt(int a1);
int callfn(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, int a5)
{
    int result;
    __asm (
            "push %[a5]\n\t"
            "push %[a4]\n\t"
            "push %[a3]\n\t"
            "call oFkt\n\t"
            "add  esp, 12"
            : "=a" (result)
            : "a" (a1), "S" (a2), [a5] "r" (a5), [a4] "r" (a4), [a3] "r" (a3)
    );
    return result;
}
```

The `=a` output constraint causes the return value to be copied into `result`,
the `a` input constraint loads `a1` in `eax`, and `S` loads `a2` into `esi`
the rest is just pushing the other arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Willem!
It gave me a good idea how it could look like. Your explanation also pointed me in the right direction for some interesting reads. I was a bit overwhelmed by the syntax before
seeing your example.